# Crypt-SSLeay on a macbook

Tags: perl

I'm trying to install Crypt-SSLeay on a macbook and it failed.

I manually downloaded Crypt-SSLeay from cpan and issued:

```
 perl Makefile.pl
```

The error is

```
openssl-version.c:2:10: fatal error: 'openssl/opensslv.h' file not found
#include <openssl/opensslv.h>
     ^
1 error generated.
Failed to build and link a simple executable using OpenSSL
```

The file exists and it's located at:

```
 /usr/local/opt/openssl/include/openssl
```

How do I go about fixing this, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Well, after trying other solutions of this and other threads to no avail, I stumbled upon this one-liner that did the trick for me:

```
$ sudo OPENSSL_INCLUDE=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include OPENSSL_LIB=/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib PERL_MM_USE_DEFAULT=1 perl -MCPAN -e "install Crypt::SSLeay"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following:

```
$ perl Makefile.PL --incpath /usr/local/opt/openssl/include --libpath /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

as per the [`Crypt-SSLeay` install docs](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Crypt-SSLeay/SSLeay.pm#OpenSSL).  (Note that the above assumes that the OpenSSL libraries, `libcrypt` and `libssl`, are installed in `/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib` on your Macbook.)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I typed this in:

```
cpanm LWP::Protocol::https
```

And then installed `Crypt-SSLeay` using:

```
cpanm Crypt::SSLeay
```

And it worked. When I tried to install `Crypt::SSLEay` before `LWP::Protocol::https` I got the same error as you originally did.

Comment: what macOS version are you using? how did you install 'cpanm' (manually, brew, conda?)